# AX2012 R2 CU7 : VSProject node compilation issues

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I am currently creating a build for Ax using TFS activities. All of the steps are in there and all of it works on a simple scenario with a couple dummy XPO's in TFS VCS. But now I need to do the full scenario of building our codebase and I'm experiencing compilation issues with the Visual Studio Project Nodes.

This is what I roughly do regarding code import/compilation:

- import label files
- import the XPO with all of the code.
- import the visual studio projects using the
  SysTreeNodeVSProject\ImportProject method

When I run a full compilation, there are still compiler errors regarding code that is in need of the resulting assemblies of the VSProjects in the AOT.

This is caused by the output of the projects still being empty. When selecting them all and hitting compile, still no result. Selecting them one by one and compiling them. The output of the projects is generated in the AOT and the depending classes can be compiled directly.

Compiling them separately cause the comiler to detect it is a VSProject node and the kernel will call the export and build functionality on the VSProjects resulting in the output being generated.

The real question here is: For my build I now have to create an AutoRun file that will compile those VSProject nodes, but isn't the compiler supposed to be doing that when doing a full compile?!

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around. I modified SysTreeNodeVSProject.importProject() to compile the tree node after it has imported.